# WPD Service api implimentation (Status Service) to get free space on WPD device

Tags: c++, windows, wpd, mtp, cgcontextdrawpdfpage

I want to get the free space on the WPD device. I am trying to implement the WPDServiceApi. I am currently implementing the status service of WPD services. i picked up the the code samples from Windows7DEK.   There are lots of type mismatches coming into existence during compilation. I am not able to build that sample at all. Initially there were a lot of missing includes which i have resolved successfully. Now i am getting type mismatches like (PSLGUID) was expected and sample is just sending (GUID) type parameter. This is just a random example. Anyone have any experience on status service? i just want to get the free space on the device.

Comment: No one who worked on Windows portable devices? thats strange..

Answer (score -1):

I've been working with such project recently, but in Delphi.

[Please look at this MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff597918(v=vs.85).aspx).

It says that `WPD Storage Properties`  supports the following storage properties.

Where `WPD_STORAGE_CAPACITY`returns the capacity of the device in BYTES.

I've used [this file as a reference](https://github.com/kovidgoyal/calibre/blob/master/src/calibre/devices/mtp/windows/device_enumeration.cpp) before, it's in Python, but easily undarstandable.

It is part of the Calibre source code.